# Insert, Update, Delete Trigger Function to audit a table

Tags: triggers, plpgsql, postgresql-9.3

I want to create a trigger function to audit the **table tb_register**:

```
    CREATE TABLE olympic.tb_register (
      athlete_id    CHARACTER(7) NOT NULL,
      round_number  INT NOT NULL,
      discipline_id INT NOT NULL,
      register_date  DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
      register_position INT DEFAULT NULL,
      register_time     TIME DEFAULT NULL,
      register_measure  REAL DEFAULT NULL,
      CONSTRAINT pk_register PRIMARY KEY (athlete_id, round_number, discipline_id),
      CONSTRAINT fk_register_athlete FOREIGN KEY (athlete_id) REFERENCES olympic.tb_athlete (athlete_id),
      CONSTRAINT fk_register_round FOREIGN KEY (discipline_id, round_number) REFERENCES olympic.tb_round (discipline_id, round_number)
    );
```

The function should upload all UPDATE, INSERT or DELETE actions to the table **tb_athlete`s_info_log** with the following structure of attributes that come from other tables.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS olympic.tb_athletes_info_log (
  athlete_id CHARACTER VARYING (7) NOT NULL,
  discipline_id INT NOT NULL,
  round_number INT NOT NULL,
  athlete_name CHARACTER VARYING (50) NOT NULL,
  discipline_name  CHARACTER VARYING (50) NOT NULL,
  mark  CHARACTER VARYING (12) NOT NULL,
  rating INT NOT NULL,
  info_log_dt DATE, 
  CONSTRAINT PK_tb_athletes_info_log PRIMARY KEY(athlete_id,discipline_id,round_number),
  CONSTRAINT fk_athlethes_info_log_register FOREIGN KEY (athlete_id, round_number, discipline_id) REFERENCES olympic.tb_register(athlete_id, round_number, discipline_id)
);
```

### This is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_athletes_info() 
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    DECLARE
          updated_athlete_id tb_register.athlete_id%type;
          updated_discipline_id tb_register.discipline_id%type;
          updated_round_number tb_register.round_number%type;
          updated_athlete_name tb_athlete.name%type;
          updated_discipline_name  tb_discipline.name%type;
          updated_mark  tb_register.register_measure%type; 
          updated_rating tb_register.register_position%type;
          updated_info_log_dt tb_register.register_ts%type; 
    BEGIN
        
        IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN 
    
            updated_athlete_id = OLD.tb_register.athlete_id;
            updated_discipline_id = OLD.tb_register.discipline_id;
            updated_round_number = OLD.tb_register.round_number;
            updated_athlete_name = OLD.tb_athlete.name;
            updated_discipline_name = OLD.tb_discipline.name;
            updated_mark = OLD.tb_register.register_measure;
            updated_rating = OLD.tb_register.register_position;
            updated_info_log_dt = OLD.tb_register.register_date;
            
         ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN 
         
            updated_athlete_id = NEW.tb_register.athlete_id;
            updated_discipline_id = NEW.tb_register.discipline_id;
            updated_round_number = NEW.tb_register.round_number;
            updated_athlete_name = NEW.tb_athlete.name;
            updated_discipline_name = NEW.tb_discipline.name;
            updated_mark = NEW.tb_register.register_measure;
            updated_rating = NEW.tb_register.register_position;
            updated_info_log_dt = NEW.tb_register.register_date;
            
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN 
        
            updated_athlete_id = NEW.tb_register.athlete_id;
            updated_discipline_id = NEW.tb_register.discipline_id;
            updated_round_number = NEW.tb_register.round_number;
            updated_athlete_name = NEW.tb_athlete.name;
            updated_discipline_name = NEW.tb_discipline.name;
            updated_mark = NEW.tb_register.register_measure;
            updated_rating = NEW.tb_register.register_position;
            updated_info_log_dt = NEW.tb_register.register_date;
            
        END IF; 
        -- Insert or update table with the new values.
        <<insert_update>>
        LOOP 
            BEGIN 
                INSERT INTO tb_athletes_info_log (
                            athlete_id,
                            discipline_id,
                            round_number,
                            athlete_name,
                            discipline_name,
                            mark,
                            rating,
                            info_log_dt)
                         
                    VALUES (
                            updated_athlete_id,
                            updated_discipline_id,
                            updated_round_number,
                            updated_athlete_name,
                            updated_discipline_name,
                            updated_mark,
                            updated_rating,
                            updated_info_log_dt
                            );
                
                EXIT insert_update; 
            EXCEPTION
                WHEN UNIQUE_VIOLATION THEN
                    -- do nothing
            END;
        END LOOP insert_update; 
        
        RETURN NULL; 
        
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER tg_athletes_info
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON tb_register
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION fn_athletes_info();
```

When I try to INSERT some data to try the tigger:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO  tb_athlete  VALUES(7777777,'xxxxxx','XXX');
INSERT INTO tb_register  VALUES(7777777,0,7,'2022-06-02 00:00:00',NULL,NULL);
COMMIT;
```

I revceive the following:

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "tb_register"
LINE 1: SELECT NEW.tb_register.athlete_id
```

I got stuck when trying to understand how to convert the data into a foramt required by the table **tb_athlete`s_info_log**

Can anyone guide me thowards a solution for this?

Thank you,
A.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess from a SQL Server (not postgresql) guy, but since no one has answered:

Where you write something like

```
updated_athlete_id = OLD.tb_register.athlete_id;
```

do you mean to mention the name of the table? I would think you just need to say OLD, not OLD.tb_register. So maybe you want this, and likewise for NEW

```
updated_athlete_id = OLD.athlete_id;
```

If postgresql is somewhat like SQL Server, the only place you should need to identify the table is in the creation of the trigger with `ON tb_register`, and I'm not sure what you would mean by `OLD.<a_table_name>.<column>`.